# Update Model Values while Create New Record using DbContext and POCO classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, poco

1)

```
public ActionResult Create(Job job)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var innerJob = new Job();
        innerJob.JobID = 100;
        TryUpdateModel(innerJob);


        db.Jobs.Add(innerJob);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Client, "ClientID", "ClientName", job.ClientID);
    ViewBag.JobOwner = new SelectList(db.User, "UserID", "LoginName", job.JobOwner);
    return View(job);
}
```

2)

```
public ActionResult Create(Job job)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        job.JobID = 100;
        db.Jobs.Add(job);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Client, "ClientID", "ClientName", job.ClientID);
    ViewBag.JobOwner = new SelectList(db.User, "UserID", "LoginName", job.JobOwner);
    return View(job);
}
```

In above both view "job" is my model coming from view. Now i wanted to insert "Id" in the newly created record. how can i do it?

the above both methods didn't work for me. i am using EF 4.3 and DataContext.

Comment: You'll get a better response if you tag with at least what language your code is in.

Comment: thanks. i have added language tag.

Comment: db.Jobs.Add(job);  job.JobID = 100;  
db.Jobs.Attach(job);  
db.SaveChanges();  this code work for me in last but actual entry didn't save in database.